# Android Studio Add Libraries and dont see class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have problem with android studio and my application. When i add custom librariers for web for example Calendar and sync gradle in my .xml file don't see class. What i do wrong?

[When i delete library then all is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loJxf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C14p7.png)

Comment: have you tried to add the package name complete?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please post text whenever possible (e.g., your second image) instead of links to images of text.

Comment: Have you tried file->invalidate caches/restart?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the full path to the fragment file

```java
    tools:context="com.example.periodapplication.CalendarFragment"
```